# Can't change the resolution higher than 1024x768

Tags: drivers, ati, xorg, resolution, xrandr

Hello complete newbie here.

So from the moment i installed ubuntu 12.04 i tried changing the resolution to the maximum supported by my monitor which is 1440x900.

I tried installing the proprietary driver but when i restart, the monitor goes out of range.If i try then and set it with xrandr it says can't open display.

I uninstalled the driver it goes back to 1024x768 and if i hit xrandr -q it shows the resolutions only till 1024x768. I'm out of ideas, i've searched on the internet like crazy and i don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone follows this question i found the answer myself.
I had a VGA to DVI adapter cause i had no room to plug the VGA cable alone so i used the DVI slot. I made room for the VGA slot and plugged the cable without the adapter and now it works.